# React - How to make the scrollbar transparent,

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Basically I created a website using htl and css, and am now porting it to react. However when I came to the scrollbar, I cannot work out how to make the background of it transparent. Here's my code,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    background-color:#94f211;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will help:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #0000;
}
```